# Difference between 特別 and 特

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Everywhere I look, they both just seem to be defined as "special" or "particularly/especially" (in the adverbial case).

I'm trying to form a distinction in my head.

Here's an example from my dictionary for 特別:

> 今日は **特別に** あつらえた服を着ます (Today I'll wear specially-ordered clothes)

Why can't it be

> 今日は **特に** あつらえた服を着ます

Or another case (from JED):

> 今朝は **特に** 寒い (today it's especially cold)

Maybe someone can provide examples for me where they can't be interchanged - or examples that emphasize the difference.
I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: I think 特に is mainly used in declarative sentences to show the speaker's attitude. You can replace it with a separate sentence like "That's unusual/uncommon". 特別に is just the manner of action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have hidden an answer in plain sight.

The example sentences you give translate 特別に as "specially" and 特に as "especially". As far as I can tell, this is exactly how you would use them in English and Japanese.

"specially" means something like "in a distinguished manner, for a particular purpose".

"especially" means something like "outstanding, noteworthy, exceptional".

Comment: Hahahaha Thanks.  Yes after consulting a Japanese friend, she explained that 特別に is more specific/exceptional.
Which, I guess, makes sense given the 別 kanji.  特別 is like **this one** as opposed to all the others.  where as 特 is just an emphasis, but is not necessarily exclusive.